# How to enable the eclipse internal browser (Ubuntu 12.10)?

Tags: 12.10, eclipse, browser

I have installed **Eclipse 4.2 x64** on **Ubuntu 12.10 x64**. I need to use the internal web browser but it is disabled by default.

The `Use internal web browser` radio button in `preferences -> General -> web browser` is disabled. How can I enable it?

I have installed Eclipse 4.2 x64 in another PC that uses Ubuntu 12.04 x64 and the internal browser works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That checkbox opens up only if you meet the criteria set in their FAQ. Copy/paste from there:

[**Question: What do I need to run the SWT Browser inside Eclipse on Linux?**](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinux):

> Answer: The browser versions that are supported by each Eclipse release are listed below. Note that Mozilla/XULRunner versions that are not final releases (eg.- betas, alphas, nightlies) are not supported, even if their version technically satisfies a listed version range. **Also note that the Mozilla/XULRunner must be compiled for the same architecture as the SWT jar that is being used**.

```
Eclipse 3.0.x: Mozilla 1.4 GTK2 - 1.6 GTK2.
Eclipse 3.1.x: Mozilla 1.4 GTK2 - 1.7.8 GTK2.
Eclipse 3.2.x: Mozilla 1.4 GTK2 - 1.7.x GTK2.
Eclipse 3.3.x: Mozilla 1.4 GTK2 - 1.7.x GTK2, XULRunner 1.8.x.
Eclipse 3.4.x: Mozilla 1.4 GTK2 - 1.7.x GTK2, XULRunner 1.8.x - 1.9.0.x.
Eclipse 3.5.0 and 3.5.1: Mozilla 1.4 GTK2 - 1.7.x GTK2, XULRunner 1.8.x - 1.9.1.x.
Eclipse 3.5.2: Mozilla 1.4 GTK2 - 1.7.x GTK2, XULRunner 1.8.x - 1.9.x and 3.6.x 
(but not 2.x).
Eclipse 3.6.x: Mozilla 1.4 GTK2 - 1.7.x GTK2, XULRunner 1.8.x - 1.9.x and 3.6.x 
(but not 2.x), WebKitGTK+ 1.2.x (see How do I use the WebKit renderer on Linux-GTK?)
Eclipse 3.7.x/4.1.x: Mozilla 1.4 GTK2 - 1.7.x GTK2, XULRunner 1.8.x - 1.9.x and 3.6.x 
(but not 2.x), WebKitGTK+ 1.2.x and newer
Eclipse 3.8.x/4.2.x: Mozilla 1.4 GTK2 - 1.7.x GTK2, XULRunner 1.8.x - 1.9.x, 3.6.x and 10.x 
(but not 2.x nor 4.x - 9.x), WebKitGTK+ 1.2.x and newer
```

> Also note that a Firefox release whose contained Gecko version correlates with the Mozilla versions above can also be used with Eclipse 3.1 and newer (Linux only), provided that it has been compiled with linkable Gecko libraries. It is important to note that Firefox downloads from mozilla.org do not satisfy this criteria, but Firefox installations that are included in major Linux distributions often do in the absence of a XULRunner installation. Attempting to use a Firefox install without linkable Gecko libraries will throw an error with message "No more handles [NS_InitEmbedding...error -2147221164]".
>
> The version of Mozilla or Firefox installed on your system varies with your Linux distribution. The following Linux distributions meet the minimum Mozilla requirements for using the Browser widget.

```
RedHat Enterprise Linux 3
Suse 9
```

---

2 things seem important:

- Mozilla/XULRunner must be compiled for the same architecture as the SWT jar that is being used.
- Eclipse 3.8.x/4.2.x: Mozilla 1.4 GTK2 - 1.7.x GTK2, XULRunner 1.8.x - 1.9.x, 3.6.x and 10.x (but not 2.x nor 4.x - 9.x), WebKitGTK+ 1.2.x and newer

---

If you meet these criteria and it still does not let you change it you might consider taking this to the Eclipse forum or filing a bug (if you are sure it is all as it should be).

Comment: what should be done so Eclipse can use latest Mozilla Firefox instead of Xulrunner on Ubuntu?

Comment: paulodiovani answered this correctly below, not sure why this attempt is marked as an answer.  Quoting paulodiovani:
I've solved the problem by installing libwebkitgtk in Ubuntu 13.10 and Eclipse Kepler.

sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
answered May 9 '14 at 23:49

paulodiovani

Comment: @david because ts never bothered to come back :=

Answer (score 12):

I've solved the problem by installing `libwebkitgtk` in Ubuntu 13.10 and Eclipse Kepler.

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

If proper webkit libraries are not installed on your system Eclipse defaults to XULRunner. That is why installing this lib solves the error. You may have to install the latest version of `libwebkitgtk` if this one doesn't work.

Comment: For over a year has I been using eclipse under ubuntu and suffering from html markup fragments all over the phpdoc-generated tooltips. Installing this package fixed that.

Comment: this also worked for me on Kubuntu14.04 + eclipse 3.8

Comment: For me libwekitgtk-3.0-0 worked, the latest version on Kubuntu 16.04.4

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines at the end of your `eclipse.ini`:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=webkit
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=true
```

This enables the use `webkit` instead of `xulrunner`.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 13.04 using Eclipse it automagically worked, I was not sure which webkit I was missing, so I installed all that seemed relevant, if someone has pinpointed which it is, please comment,

Regards,

Gabriel Medina

```
aptitude install libqt4-webkit libqt5webkit5 libqtscript4-webkit libqtwebkit4 libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
```

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 from 12.04 a few days ago. The problem I 
noticed between Eclipse(Kepler) and Ubuntu 14.04 is that the Internal 
Web Browser of Eclipse was disabled. The trick was to install 
libwebkitgtk-1.0.0. Ubuntu 14.04 comes with libwebkitgtk-3.0.0 
preinstalled which is incompatible with SWT which is used by Eclipse.

---

> sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0

---

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is just to add the current running browser path to the eclipse->window->preferences->general->web browser->.
Now check the `use external web browser`. Click on `add` and add the path of your browser into it and hit apply.

To know your browser path in ubuntu just type `which firefox` in terminal and hit enter. You will get the path .

I found this solution after 5 hours and trying lots of methods to do this:  xulrunner, webkit etc etc but the best and working for everyone is this. Thumbs up happy coding.